# Javascript on load not loading to update page any ideas?

Tags: javascript-objects

When I run the following Javascript Onload code is'nt updating the html element any ideas?

It show no errors in the browser.

''''

```
<head>

<title> Planets </title>


<script>
    function init()
    {var planet = document.getElementById("GreenPlanet");
    
    planet.innerHtml="Red Alert hit by a laser";

}

 window.onload=init;


 </script>


 </head>


  <h1>Green Planet </h1> 
    <p id="GreenPlanet">Nothing to report </p>

  </body>

 </html> ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

The `innerHtml` parameter should be `innerHTML`